# Error during build release version of app after update Gradle and AGP 7.x

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

During migration to new Gradle version (7.0.2) and Android Google plugin (7.0.3), I'm facing with an exception in legacy project. Project have multiple modules and libraries configured with company maven repository.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':collect*FLAVOR*Dependencies'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':collect*FLAVOR*Dependencies' property 'projectRepositories'.
   > repo.url must not be null

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':collect*FLAVOR*Dependencies'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:408)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:395)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:388)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException: Failed to query the value of task ':collect*FLAVOR*Dependencies' property 'projectRepositories'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.doCalculateValue(AbstractProperty.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.getOrNull(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.annotations.NestedBeanAnnotationHandler.unpackProvider(NestedBeanAnnotationHandler.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.annotations.NestedBeanAnnotationHandler.visitPropertyValue(NestedBeanAnnotationHandler.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.visitProperties(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.RootRuntimeBeanNode.visitNode(RootRuntimeBeanNode.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultPropertyWalker.visitProperties(DefaultPropertyWalker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskPropertyUtils.visitProperties(TaskPropertyUtils.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultTaskProperties.resolve(DefaultTaskProperties.java:65)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveMutations(LocalTaskNode.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.getResolvedMutationInfo(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:654)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.selectNext(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:577)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$executeNextNode$1(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.resources.DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.withStateLock(DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.java:45)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:155)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: repo.url must not be null
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PerModuleReportDependenciesTask$CreationAction$Companion.toInternalRepoMetadataList$gradle_core(PerModuleReportDependenciesTask.kt:264)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PerModuleReportDependenciesTask$CreationAction$configure$1.transform(PerModuleReportDependenciesTask.kt:325)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PerModuleReportDependenciesTask$CreationAction$configure$1.transform(PerModuleReportDependenciesTask.kt:325)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.mapValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$ElementsFromCollectionProvider.collectEntries(Collectors.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$CollectingSupplier.calculateValue(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:337)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.calculateValueFrom(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.calculateValueFrom(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.doCalculateValue(AbstractProperty.java:133)
    ... 22 more
```

Anyone knows what could cause this exception or where I should dig?

I ran assembleDebug with success.

Comment: Remember, whenever you have an error in any gradle build, post your build files.

Comment: I found these resources, which may help you too: 
https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/299#issuecomment-898311188 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162074215#comment9